# Is there a word like 'Master' better fit for describing businesses?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, synonyms

How would you describe a company that has achieved mastery in a particular field?

I feel that, even though 'master' gets the message through, it doesn't work very well in a *business context*.

I'm searching for a meaning like '*established*', but I would prefer a noun so that it has a marketing feel to it, to be able to form sort phrases that sound good, like what I try to achieve in the examples below.

The focus has to be on the know-how and applications, not on the pioneering/ leading/ innovation side of things.

Example sentences:

> This company is a *'Master' of Consulting*.
>
> Microsoft is a software 'Master'.

English is my second language so your perspective is crucial! Any suggestions or insights you may have will be of great help.

Comment: In terms of naming or describing a business, "master" is a bit pretentious.  The term should be reserved for credentialed individuals: "master carpenter", "master plumber", etc.

Comment: One term would be *brand leaders*. Branding is what successful long-established businesses are known for.

Answer (score 1):

**[Market Leader](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/market-leader.asp?layout=orig&adtest=5noninfinite)**  the interpretation is pretty straightforward: within their market, consulting or software, they are the have the largest market share.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **dominant**

> 1
>   a :  commanding, controlling, or prevailing over all others < the dominant culture >
>
> b :  very important, powerful, or successful < a dominant theme > < a dominant industry >

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominant)

Answer (score 0):

How about '[first-rate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/first-rate)':

> 1.
>   excellent; superb.
>
> 2.
>   of the highest rank, rate, or class.

Using it in your example sentences:

This company is *first-rate* at consulting.

Microsoft is a *first-rate* software company.

Another option may be '[world-class](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/world-class)' but this is slightly more informal and self-aggrandizing than the former (although perfectly suitable when describing a Goliath such as Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

Master is actually an appropriate word for certain types of businesses, *eg* [Master Locksmiths](http://insafe.com/services/master-locksmiths/), [Master Milliner](http://www.pariskyne.com/). More generic terms that can be applied to almost any commercial enterprise are:

**Experts**

> having or showing special skill or knowledge because of what you have been taught or what you have experienced - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert)

*eg* [IT Experts](http://www.bestitexperts.com/)

**Specialists**

> a person who has special knowledge and skill relating to a particular job, area of study, *etc*. - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specialist)

*eg* [Software Specialists](http://www.softwarespecialists.com/)

**Professionals**

> relating to a job that requires special education, training, or skill - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/professional)

*eg* [Headwear Professionals](http://www.workwearclothingonline.com.au/HEADWEAR-PROFESSIONALS/)